# get an element from an arraylist of one class to be used in another class

Tags: java, arraylist

I need help in getting an element of an ArrayList of one class and using it in another.

The task is basically allocating task entered in Job class which is placed in an arraylist in JobQueue class. The issue im having at the moment is that i have a duration as integers for each task within Job class and im trying to get a total duration utilised in JobQueue class if there is more than 1 task enetered.

Task:- get totalDuration of jobs in Job class to be used inside JobQueue class.

Here is what i have so far.

```
//first class that contains jobs created.
public class Job
{  
//fields  
private String jobName;
private int jobDuration;
private static final int DEFAULT_DURATION = 0;

public Job(String task, int duration)
{
    //constructor used to create the job name and how long it will take to do one job (duration).
    jobName = task;
    if (duration > DEFAULT_DURATION)
    {
        jobDuration = duration;
    }
    else
    {
        jobDuration = DEFAULT_DURATION;            
    }
}
public String getName()
{
    return jobName;
}

public int getDuration()
{
    return jobDuration;
}
}

// 2nd class used to enter every job created into an Arraylist called myJobs.
public class JobQueue
{
private ArrayList <Job> myJobs;
private int totalDuration;
private static final int DEFAULT_NUM = 0;

public JobQueue()
{
    myJobs = new ArrayList<Job>();
    totalDuration = DEFAULT_NUM;
}
public ArrayList<Job> getPendingJobs()
{
    return myJobs;
}
public void addJob(Job job)
{
    myJobs.add(job);
}
}
//here i need a method that gets the total duration of jobs in the arraylist and returns total as an integer. Please help.
```

Comment: Is it the queue iteration/looping you're having problems with ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be your method, not much to it:

```
int totalDuration() {
  int totalDuration = 0;
  for (Job j : myJobs) totalDuration += j.getDuration();
  return totalDuration;
}
```

You also have a `totalDuration` property that could be seen as a cached total duration value. This should be introduced only as a necessary evil, an optimization due to a noticed performance problem. If that is not your case, remove the property. If you really do need it, given your current API (jobs are only added), you could maintain the total value by changing your `addJob` method:

```
public void addJob(Job job)
{
    myJobs.add(job);
    totalDuration += job.getDuration();
}
```

And then your required method to get the total duration would be just

```
int totalDuration() { return totalDuration; }
```

However, as your code's complexity grows, it usually becomes increasingly difficult to mantain the total duration invariant and there's a breaking point where you must be very clear that you really need its speed advantage.

Comment: good point, but you need to subtract duration of removed jobs too.

Comment: @logoff I don't notice a remove method in OP's code and I pointed that out in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response guys and help guys issue solved.

Answer (score 2):

Do a loop to get the total duration

```
public int getTotalDuration() {
    int total = 0;
    for(Job job : myJobs) {
        total += job.getDuration();
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: +1 You win the speed race, but the OP asks for `Integer` result, not `int` - maybe it doesn't matter that much due to autoboxing

Comment: But there's a typo, it should be `total += ...` instead of `result += ...`.

Comment: @Bohemian, he said `integer`, not `Integer`. `int` is the perfect response, you don't need a class wrapper to store a simple integer. Even if he said `Integer`, I had preferred an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the purpose, I don't think you should have a `totalDuration` property for the `JobQueue` class. Instead, create a method, called something like `getTotalDuration` and have it loop through all `Job`s in the `myJob` property, adding up each individual `Job`'s `jobDuration`.

```
public int getTotalDuration() {
    int totalDuration = 0;
    for (Job job : this.myJobs) {
        totalDuration += job.getDuration();
    }
    return totalDuration;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the total duration of all the jobs in the job list, simply loop through the ArrayList and sum up the durations of each individual task:

```
public int getDuration()
{
    int totalDuration = 0;
    for (Job job : myJobs)
    {
        totalDuration += job.getDuration();
    }
    return totalDuration;
}
```

Note that this is a simplistic approach to the problem, because there are other considerations that might be important to you.  For example, if job names are unique, you might want to perform special behavior when you come across a duplicate job name.  If you want to ignore duplicates, for example, you could keep a HashSet of names that you've encountered already.  In any case, you need to determine the desired behavior for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int getDuration(){

    int totalDuration=0;

    for(Iterator<Job> it =myJobs.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ){
        Job job = it.next();
        totalDuration+=job.getDuration();
    }

    return totalDuration;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Job job : getPendingJobs())
{
    totalDuration += job.getDuration();
}
```

That's all

Answer (score 0):

iterate over the arraylist and sum up the jobDuration of each job instance.

```
 for(Job j: jobList) {
      //sum up all the durations here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```
//first class that contains jobs created.
public class Job {
    //fields  
    private String jobName;
    private int jobDuration;
    private static final int DEFAULT_DURATION = 0;
    JobQueue queue = new JobQueue(); // Intialize the object.. Now queue.myJobs = a new array list of jobs.

    public Job(String task, int duration) {
        //constructor used to create the job name and how long it will take to do one job (duration).
        jobName = task;
        if (duration > DEFAULT_DURATION)
        {
            jobDuration = duration;
        }
        else
        {
            jobDuration = DEFAULT_DURATION;            
        }

        queue.addJob(this);

    }
    public String getName() {
        return jobName;
    }

    public int getDuration() {
        return jobDuration;
    }
}

// 2nd class used to enter every job created into an Arraylist called myJobs.
public class JobQueue {
    private ArrayList <Job> myJobs;
    private int totalDuration = 0;
    private static final int DEFAULT_NUM = 0;

    public JobQueue() {
        myJobs = new ArrayList<Job>();
        totalDuration = DEFAULT_NUM;
    }
    public ArrayList<Job> getPendingJobs() {
        return myJobs;
    }
    public void addJob(Job job) {
        myJobs.add(job);
        totalDuration += job.getDuration(); // It would be easier instead of looping through it, just to add to the total duration when the job is added to the queue.
    }

    public void getTotalDuration() {
        return totalDuration;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you `add` method

```
public void addJob(Job job)
{
    myJobs.add(job);
    totalDuration += job.getDuration();
}
```

Now you have `getTotalDuration()` method to just return `totalDuration.` You will need to subtract removed jobs also.

```
public void getTotalDuration() {
    return totalDuration;
}
```